# Why does DotNetNuke unexpectedly replace my DOM elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I am developing a 9.13 DotNetNuke custom module and on one of my settings pages a have a custom input field to upload files to my API controller, but whenever I try to make ANY ajax request to the server, DNN automatically replaces my file input field styles, so it creates a span with `dnnInputFileWrapper` class, and it overrides my original input field. Additionally, it removes event handlers. Here is how my DOM looks before the ajax request:

```html
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-file" tabindex="500">
   <i class="bi-folder2-open"></i>
   <span class="hidden-xs">Browse …</span>
   <input id="my-input" type="file" multiple="">
</div>
```

And after:

```html
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-file" tabindex="500">
   <i class="bi-folder2-open"></i>  
   <span class="hidden-xs">Browse …</span>
   <span class="dnnInputFileWrapper dnnSecondaryAction">Choose File
      <input id="my-input" type="file" multiple="">
   </span>
</div>
```

And UI looks like so:

[image: before ajax request]

[image: after ajax request]

I tried to overwrite the default DotNetNuke CSS classes and it worked fine until I faced the problem with removed event handlers

Comment: Why?  Because that's what it's for.

Comment: @freedomn-m is there any way to prevent the behavior? Can I control that?

Comment: You're using a UI framework then asking "how do I not use the UI framework" - Answer: don't use dotnetnuke?   I can't see the screenshots, so maybe there's more to it.

Comment: @freedomn-m It's not an option for me not to use dotnetnuke, in my case i want to make a custom file input field, and it looks like DNN doesn't allow me to do that, but I'am 100% sure, that there is a way to do that, because i've seen some modules with custom elements such as file input fields

Comment: @freedomn-m My custom styles render fine, but any ajax request triggers some built in functions which add the span with the class 'dnnInputFileWrapper'

Comment: DNN still exists? Wow.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer. If you're facing the problem you should add the `normalFileUpload` class to your input field `type="file"`.

After inspecting DotNetNuke dnn.jquery.js file I found the function which handles the wrapping functionality and the line of code which allow us to avoid this behaviour and it looks like this:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.dnnFileInput = function (options) {
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.dnnFileInput.defaultOptions, options);

    return this.each(function () {
      var $ctrl = $(this);
      if ($ctrl.hasClass('normalFileUpload')) return;

      if (this.wrapper)
        return;

      //ignore decoration for elements in rad control.
      if ($ctrl.parents().hasClass("RadUpload"))
        return;

      // if this.wrapper is undefined, then we check if parent node is a wrapper
      if (this.parentNode && this.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span' && $ctrl.parent().hasClass('dnnInputFileWrapper')) {
        return;
      }

      this.wrapper = $("<span class='dnnInputFileWrapper " + opts.buttonClass + "'></span>");
      var text = $ctrl.data('text');
      text = text || 'Choose File';
      this.wrapper.text(text);
      $ctrl.wrap(this.wrapper);
      $ctrl.data("wrapper", $ctrl.parent());

      if (opts.showSelectedFileNameAsButtonText) {
        $ctrl.change(function () {
          var val = $(this).val();
          if (val != '') {
            var lastIdx = val.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
            val = val.substring(lastIdx, val.length);
          } else {
            val = text;
          }
          $(this).data("wrapper").get(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue = val;
        });
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.dnnFileInput.defaultOptions = {
    buttonClass: 'dnnSecondaryAction',
    showSelectedFileNameAsButtonText: true
  };
})(jQuery);
```

At least it works with DNN version 9.13